# Making executable file on OSX from a python script

Tags: python, macos, ubuntu, exe

I need to make executable file on OSX/Mac. I have python3 script that uses excel file. Executable file also should be able to work just by double clicking the icon and also have python packages. I mainly work with Ubuntu18 but have access to Mac for few days.

What I've tried so far:

- I've written a short bash script that activates python environment (with "source activate" command) and runs python script. Appified the script with this: https://gist.github.com/anmoljagetia/d37da67b9d408b35ac753ce51e420132
  I know that terminal commands work but double-clicking the app in Mac does nothing.
- With pyinstaller converted bash+python script to exe, then with wine tried converting that to executable program but that double-clicked program does nothing.
- Tried py2app, but in the mac terminal it says "cannot execute binary file".

Does someone have any recommendations for my problem? As I've mentioned there are few main requirements:

- works by double-clicking
- works on mac
- has all python packages
- is able to read specific excel file (I will know the name of it, but just path may be confusing in some versions, because I would like to use relative path or something like [pwd]/file.xlsx)

Anyway, I'm having most problems with the first two points but don't want to forget the last two.

Thank You for help!

Comment: This has already been answered here: https://superuser.com/questions/1164706/how-do-i-make-a-python-file-executable-on-macos-sierra/1164713